# Confusion about correlation coefficient between two zero almost surely random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, correlation

Let $X=Y=0$ almost surely. Since both random variables have zero variance, $\rho_{XY}=\frac{0}{0}$. However, in the part (b) of the following theorem from Casella & Berger (2002, page 172):

[image]

it seems that $\lvert \rho_{XY} \rvert =1$ because $a$ can be any non-zero real number and $b=0$. So, which is the correct value of $\rho_{XY}$?

Comment: There may be a general assumption that RVs aren't almost surely constant in the book.

Comment: There is not such an assumption in the book. It could be a mistake in the writing of the theorem.

Comment: Unless there's a convention for $\rho_{XY}$ when (at least) one of the RVs is almost surely constant (also, when one isn't square integrable), it ought to be a hypothesis of the theorem that $\rho_{XY}$ exists.

Comment: Usual definition $\rho$ has $SD(X)SD(Y)$ in denom, If $SD(X)=0$ or $SD(Y)=0,$ then $\rho$ is undefined. If Thm needs condition in order to be true, then state counterexample and necessary condition.